# How to sanitize and validate user input to pass a Checkmarx scan

Tags: java, security, code-analysis, static-code-analysis, checkmarx

I have an endpoint that receives a String from the client as seen below:

```
@GET
@Path("/{x}")
public Response doSomething(@PathParam("x") String x) {
    String y = myService.process(x);
    return Response.status(OK).entity(y).build();
}
```

Checkmarx complains that this element’s value then *"flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually displayed to the user in method doSomething"*

Then I tried this:

```
@GET
@Path("/{x}")
public Response doSomething(@PathParam("x") String x) {
    if (StringUtils.trimToNull(x) == null || x.length() > 100) { 
        throw new RuntimeException(); 
    }
    x = x.replace("'", "").replace("`", "").replace("\\", "").replace("\"", "")
    String y = myService.process(x);
    y = y.replace("'", "").replace("`", "").replace("\\", "").replace("\"", "")
    return Response.status(OK).entity(y).build();
}
```

But it still considers this a high severity vulnerability.

How do I properly sanitize or validate to pass a Checkmarx scan?

Comment: I am facing the same issue and even after trying  y =HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(x)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[HtmlUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html) from `spring-web` got the job done with:

`HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(x)`

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: it worked for me , my issue is sonar is giving XSS issue on the input of type String for one of the method in controller class , i did leading trailing whitepsaces ,but still issue is present , so i used HtmlUtils.htmlEscape and it worked fine for me

Comment: Does this work only with Spring 5? I tried adding to the path parameter string. But I still get the same issue in check marx

Answer (score 3):

in .Net framework > 4.0 use AntiXSS

`AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode()`

Comment: it has to be applied to property by property or some common way to achieve this?